# Is there a good place to keep updated on Carcassonne News?

Tags: carcassonne, expansions

I'm not sure if this fits, if not let me know and I'll delete it.

I have many/most of the Carcassonne expansions and have spent way too much money doing so.  However my biggest problem is finding out when new expansions are going to become available.  This is a royal pain and I was wondering if anyone has a website or email list that can be watched that gives good timely announcements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a member of Carcassonne Central. We have about a dozen forums for discussing various aspects of Carcassonne including breaking news, new expansions, general gameplay tips, tournaments and various other projects etc. It's well worth a look if you want to meet with other Carcassonne enthusiasts/ addicts around the world, and it's very friendly too!

Answer (score 4):

Boardgame Geek's [*Carcassonne* family page](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgamefamily/2/carcassonne); which collects information on all of the *Carcassonne* games. You can also search for "Carcassonne" and get a list of all the games and subscribe to the individual games of interest.

Just sign up, click "Subscribe" and you will stay up to date on all *Carcassonne* news.